# BigQuery - Update schema adding a NULL column in arbitrary position from Python client

Tags: python, google-bigquery, database-schema

**Background**

I would like to update the schema of a table in BigQuery to match the schema of another table that contains a superset of the original columns. I would like to do it through the BigQuery Python client.

**Problem**

In practice I want to add some columns containing `NULL` to an already existing BigQuery table at an arbitrary position that is not necessarily the beginning or the end.

I know how to append new columns at the **end** of a table, following this [snippet](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#manually_adding_an_empty_column), but I would like to add columns in an arbitrary position. Moreover I would like to do it through a schema update, without having to query the entire table.

Being that the schema is actually a list of `SchemaField` objects, I thought that substituting the `append` method with the `insert` method would have sufficed. But this snippet does not do what I'd like:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_id = 'my_dataset'
table_id = 'my_table'

table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)
table = client.get_table(table_ref)  # API request

original_schema = table.schema

new_schema = original_schema[:]  # creates a copy of the schema
# insert new_col at position 2, instead of appending
new_schema.insert(2, bigquery.SchemaField('new_col', 'STRING')) 

table.schema = new_schema
table = client.update_table(table, ['schema'])  # API request
```

This code results in the schema being updated exactly as if the method called was `append`, i.e. `new_col` gets placed at the end of the schema.

**Question**

Do you know if it's possible to **modify the schema** of a BigQuery table so that the new (`NULL`) columns are inserted at **an arbitrary** position?

Answer (score 0):

as per the answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740838/inserting-new-columns-in-the-middle-of-a-table) I would suggest that to copy half table, add the required column and then add join the of the old table would be a possibility, really more expensive than add just a new column at the end, but still a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

as explained [on this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61978/how-to-change-the-column-order), such functionality doesn't exist in any SQL server, as column order is irrelevant. what could be done, is to append the new column, and then e.g. scramble the columns order and recreate the table with random column order. What is your business need for this?