# BigQuery insert (not append) a new column into schema

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a convenient way (Python, web UI, or CLI) for inserting a new column into an existing BigQuery table (that already has 100 columns or so) and update the schema accordingly?

Say I want to insert it after column 49. If I do this via a query, I will have to type every single column name, will I not?

**Update:** the suggested answer does not make it clear how this applies to BigQuery. Furthermore, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_set_options_statement) does not seem to cover

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD `column_name1` TEXT NOT NULL AFTER `column_name2`;
```

Syntax. A test confirmed that the `AFTER` identifier does not work for BigQuery.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting new columns in the middle of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740838/inserting-new-columns-in-the-middle-of-a-table)

Comment: @FernandoCid No, it does not

Comment: BigQuery doesn't allow you to insert a column in the middle right now. You'll have to recreate the table and migrate the data over. `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ... AS SELECT ..." allows you to do this in one operation.

Comment: @FabianBosler, do you mind explaining a little why you need to insert a column after a specific column? Is this to support `SELECT * FROM ...` without manually adjusting order of column or you have more complex scenario to support?

Comment: @YunZhang It's really only for cosmetic reasons. I value descriptions and structure. The table in question is a base table and I actually do expect people to look at the Schema and read the column description and I want to keep columns together that should logically be close to each other. I guess a `SELECT * EXCEPT (cols_after), new col, cols after` at least reduces the number of col names to type.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not possible to perform this action in a simple way, I thought in some workarounds to reach this such as:

1. [Create a view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views) after adding your column.
2. [Creating a table from a query result](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_a_table_from_a_query_result) after adding your column.

On the other hand, I can't catch how this is useful, the only scenario I can think for this requirement is if you are using `SELECT *`  which is not recommended when using BigQuery according with the [Bigquery best practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#avoid_select_). If is not the case share your case of use to get a better understanding of it.

Since this is not a current feature of BigQuery you can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) asking for this feature.

Comment: It's really only for cosmetic reasons. I value descriptions and structure. The table in question is a base table and I actually do expect people to look at the schema and read the column description and I want to keep columns together that should logically be close to each other. I guess a SELECT * EXCEPT (cols_after), new col, cols after at least reduces the number of col names to type

Comment: SELECT * EXCEPT (col) is a good approach after creates a table from a query result, especially if you want to get the [schema information](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro) for your users.